# Angular 5 - using the same path for different modules

Tags: angular, angular5, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

if you guys happened to be facebook users, you perhaps noticed the Url "**https://www.facebook.com**" does not change when the user is logged in or out. I had the same problem in an application I'm building (using angular 5). Though there have been some suggested solutions for that:

1. First is to use the same route, one component (say: home), and inside home's template we insert the in,out (components) with *ngIf, at run time we check if the user is logged in or out and based on that we show the corresponding (in or out) component.

> home.component.html

```
<app-in *ngIf="loggedIn"></app-in>
<app-out *ngIf="!loggedIn"></app-out>
```

2. The second approach that I thought would be cleaner, especially when using **lazy loading**, is to have two routes with the same empty path successively, and protect (say: the first one) with a **matcher**, now honestly this still ugly since matcher was not intended for such advanced usage (It's also sync and is not wrapped in a service -such as **canLoad**, **canActivate**..etc- where one can easily inject some other service (ex: **authService**) to check if one is logged in or out).

> home.routing.ts

```
.
.
.

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    matcher: matcherFunc,
    loadChildren: './in/in.module#InModule'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: './out/out.module#OutModule'
  }
];

.
.
.
```

and this is the matcher function:

```
export function matcherFunc(url: UrlSegment[]) {
  let currentUser;


    currentUser = localStorage.getItem('user');

  if (url.length === 0 && currentUser) {
    return ({ consumed: url });
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

The problem got even worse when I upgraded my app to be **universal**, since in that scenario I had to deal with global variables (window, localStorage..etc) on the **server side** where I was totally trapped!

I believe this question has been there for a while now with no satisfying answer, any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Module that handles what module should be load by providing the ROUTES of the RouterModule using the useFactory provider of Angular.

The code could be something like that.

```
// HandlerModule

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ROUTES,
      useFactory: configHandlerRoutes,
      deps: [SessionService],
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})


export class HandlerModule {}

export function configHandlerRoutes(sessionService: SessionService) {
  let routes: Routes = [];
  if (sessionService.isLoggedIn()) {
    routes = [
      {
        path: '', loadChildren: './in/in.module#InModule'
      }
    ];
  } else {
    routes = [
      {
        path: '', loadChildren: './out/out.module#OutModule'
      }
    ];
  }
  return routes;
}
```

Then in your AppRoutingModule the module of the path '' is going to be the HandlerModule:

```
// AppRoutingModule

 {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: './handler/handler.module#HandlerModule'
 }
```

After in the SessionService you have to update the Router.config when the value that provides the method isLoggedIn changes, because the application will only load the page (module) that had loaded the first time. This is because the function “configHandlerRoutes” use by the useFactory provider in the HandlerModule is only executed the first time we navigate to the “” path and after that the Angular Router already know which module he has to load.

In conclusion in the SessionService you have to do:

```
  export class SessionService {
  private loggedIn: boolean;
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.loggedIn = false;
  }

  public isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    return this.loggedIn;
  }

  public setLoggedIn(value: boolean): void {
    const previous = this.loggedIn;
    this.loggedIn = value;
    if (previous === this.loggedIn) {
      return;
    }
    const i = this.router.config.findIndex(x => x.path === '');
    this.router.config.splice(i, 1);
    this.router.config.push(
      {path: '', loadChildren: () => import('app/handler/handler.module').then(mod => mod.HandlerModule)}
    );
  }
}
```

That's it.

If you want another reference here is an article where they use the same approach: https://medium.com/@german.quinteros/angular-use-the-same-route-path-for-different-modules-or-components-11db75cac455

Comment: This approach did work for me, but suddenly I had to add all the (non-lazy) components to the `entryComponents` array when providing the `ROUTES` token. Do you know why?

Comment: Hi @devqon , when I did it with Angular 8 it wasn't necessary to add them in the ```entryComponents```, here it's my repo: https://github.com/gquinteros93/same-path-for-different-modules

Are you using those components in other modules?

Comment: Might be because I have it a bit different; there is a 'legacy' component which is eagerly loaded in the route, but now I want to have a switch which will load a whole feature module lazy. I will dive into it, but currently I had to revert this approach because of other issues with sub-routing

Comment: Hi @German Quinteros
Can you please provide a stackblitz for this. I have an error of path not found after add this solution.

Comment: Hi @mayurkukadiya , here you have the Github repo with the solution: https://github.com/gquinteros93/same-path-for-different-modules

Comment: Thanks a lot @German Quinteros. It would help me a lot.